# Programmatically position a button Android

Tags: android, android-relativelayout

Hi I have my layout like so:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/BlanchedAlmond" >

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</RelativeLayout >
```

I programmatically add a button like so:

```
    ImageButton startButton = new ImageButton(this);
    startButton.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.startbutton));

    addContentView(startButton, new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
```

Can anyone guide me as to how I could get the button placed at the bottom and centered. I have seen other questions that are similar but I have not been able to achieve what I am looking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give an `id` to your `RelativeLayout` as below to add new view to this layout later...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/BlanchedAlmond" >

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</RelativeLayout >
```

Now, create `ImageButton` and add to the activity layout as follows...

```
RelativeLayout rootLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout);

ImageButton startButton = new ImageButton(this);
startButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);

RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM);
lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);

rootLayout.addView(startButton, lp);
```

Comment: @HS +1 up for your _Awesome_ answer!

Answer (score 1):

You can simply add `rules` encapsulated with `verbs` to your `LayoutParams`

**For Example** :

```
ImageButton startButton = new ImageButton(this);
startButton.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.startbutton));

LayoutParams lp = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM);
lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);

addContentView(startButton, lp);
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you, I am getting an error on addRule : Undefined for the type ViewGroup.LayoutParams